# Mustache-like templating language with extends?

Tags: javascript, mustache, client-side-templating, hogan.js

I like the minimal-ness of mustache-style templating languages - I'm currently using [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) and icanhasmustache, but I've also checked out [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and [hogan](http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/).

However I have a need to for an 'extends' type functionality, to allow a child to reference a particular parent template. I can't find documentation on how extends are implemented in any of the above, but I've seen (from random githib gists) that other people seem to be doing it.

**Note**: I'm aware of the existence of includes (sometimes called partials), however these seems to be for a  parent to reference a particular child. That's the opposite of what I'm looking for - the child template in this case is the real 'base' document, the parent merely incidental, so I want the child to control the relationship.

Comment: Maybe this will help (faking template extend in mustache.js) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925931/can-mustache-templates-do-template-extension

Comment: @WTK Thanks. I've seen that answer - mustache itself doesn't do it. My question is perhaps: does anything else? Using a static function per #2 in the ticked answer means you'd need a function for each parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's implementation of Mustache, Hogan, seems to support inheritance now.

See this recent commit: [Hogan 3. Add template inheritance...](https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/commit/73ec68b72df84553cccb55bc6dd69c198c13723a)

Answer (score 8):

**2016 answer**:

If you're using express, the layout middleware takes a `layout` option which you may find useful.

```
res.render('page', { layout: 'mylayout.jade' })
```

**original answer**: Very few JS libraries implement 'extends'-type functionality.

- [Nun](https://github.com/akaspin/nun) is very mustache like, but server only (and no longer maintained)
- [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig) has extends, but isn't very mustache like.
- [Jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) has extends and works in the browser, but isn't mustache like

I settled on [Dust.JS](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/#dust), as it uses mustache-like sections, works on client and server, and supports overriding blocks on the parent from the child, giving effective extends support.

See the dust documentation, 'Blocks and Inline Partials' section:

```
{>base_template/}
{<title}
  Child Title
{/title}
{<main}
  Child Content
{/main}
```

Overriding the 'title' and 'main' sections from the parent template, keeping the surrounding contents.

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking into Nunjucks, which promises to fix some issues as well as support inheritance.

- http://jlongster.com/2012/09/20/nunjucks.html
- https://github.com/jlongster/nunjucks

EDIT:

I have indeed adopted Nunjucks, it's pretty solid so far. One limitation I've encountered is that you can't specify multiple folders for precompiling, but I wrote a script to allow it.